# Pixel Information from NSImage (Swift)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsimage

How could I extract information about pixels (such as number of pixels on width and height and RGB value for each pixel) from an NSImage in Swift?

Comment: Check code in objective C, swift is similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics

Answer (score 2):

You can send [`-size`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSImage/size) to the image itself.

However, to get detailed data you should not ask the image itself, but one of its representations, that are instances of a subclass of `NSImageRep`. The attributes you can get depends on the type of the representation. Likely you will have a [`NSBitmapImageRep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBitmapImageRep).
 To test a pixel, you can use [`-colortAtX:y:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBitmapImageRep_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBitmapImageRep/colorAtX:y:).